# docker copy file from image to host generate unkown symbols and numbers begining and ending of the file content

Tags: docker, dockerfile

What cause all these strange symbols and numbers got inserted with I use docker copy? I can't copy content in the post for stackoverflow, because all the strange symbols and number will be erased the moment I past it here.

How the `strange symbols and numbers` look like:
[image: nt]

command I used to copy the file from image:

```
# copy from an image to local

id=$(docker create an-image-example)

docker cp $id:/app/report/junit.xml - > ./aaa.xml
docker rm -v $id
```

Also good to note that before I see the content, VS Code will warn me first with:
[image]

Comment: Why do you redirect the command output to a file ? (using `>`). I mean why don't you copy the file ? Like this : `docker cp $id:/app/report/junit.xml /path/to/local/folder`

Comment: Because it kept telling me the 2nd path is a directory

Comment: Did you try with a filename ? Like so `docker cp $id:/app/report/junit.xml /path/to/local/folder/local_junit.xml`

Comment: Uhm.... That's exactly what I did though? It's described in the question.... Or maybe I am not understanding your question?

Comment: `docker cp $id:/app/report/junit.xml - > ./aaa.xml` is different from  `docker cp $id:/app/report/junit.xml /path/to/local/folder/local_junit.xml`

Comment: Ah I see! Going to try that... Curious what that - >  does in this case? Anything special?

Comment: I am not entirely sure but I guess: The position where you wrote "-" is the supposed destination folder/file path. You're telling docker to cp to a folder named "-" (which may produce an error) while with `>` you're redirecting the output of the error in a file named "aaa.xml"

Comment: @Flo you can turn your comments into an answer. you nailed it! Thanks

Comment: That's fine if you fixed it! i'm here to help, not to get some points :p

Comment: (Hats off) Just thought you deserve it regardless. hehe. Thanks a lot!